# SSH Public Key Authentication not automounting encrypted drive

Tags: ssh, ecryptfs, keyrings

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server where the user's home directory is encrypted. I have followed a guide that says to get Public Key Authentication working with ecryptfs, you need to:

1. Make a `home/.ssh directory`.
2. Move your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/home/.ssh/`
3. Modify `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to: `/home/.ssh/%u`
4. Create symbolic link: `ln -s /home/.ssh/username ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
5. Create an unmounted `~/.profile` containing `ecryptfs-mount-private`

While public key authentication definitely works after doing the above, the problem I have is that `ecrypt-mount-private` is now prompting me for my password.

Is there any way of auto-mounting my encrypted directory without having to enter a password?

Comment: For decryption, you need the password (which is used to encrypt that directory). AFAIK, there is no way to decrypt the directory using public key.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje. I have reluctantly decrypted my home folder for now.